# How exactly is human ignorance maintained in the nWoD?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-1e

Is there an official sourcebook for the new World of Darkness (not any of the core rulebooks) that goes into more detail on how humanity remains or is kept ignorant of all the supernatural phenomena that surrounds it? (How is the general "[Masquerade](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Masquerade)" — not just that of the Vampires — held up?) All of the core books deal with this, but I find the reasoning… lacking somewhat, hence why I'm looking for sources beyond the core rulebooks.

If not, is there any widely accepted and recommended unofficial material? (Perhaps some "actual play" thread that concerns itself primarily with this aspect of the nWoD?)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your best bet for sourcebooks is to look at those from the core World of Darkness line. Two that address the issue most directly are **Tales from the 13th Precinct** (which covers things from a police perspective) and, surprisingly, **World of Darkness: Innocents** (which offers a great view of the average person in the WoD through the eyes of their kids).

Answer (score 12):

Humanity doesn't notice because, in general, it doesn't want to. Each race has a reason to preserve its own secrecy, and generally the tools to do so. Between Vampires being immune to being caught on tape/photographs, werewolves causing lunacy, and the Guardians of the Veil coming in to clean things up, humanity doesn't stand much of a chance.

I do not think there're specific rules for it, but I know the core books theme is all about regular humans peeking beneath the surface, and what happens to them. Likewise, Innocents is about children that don't realize these things don't exist yet.

Why and how humans remain ignorant matters greatly to the style and theme of your game. The idea of nWod is that there are secrets, many of which people refuse, or are too busy, to acknowledge.

Comment: Generally if I need a MIB to come in and clean things up, the Guardians of the Vale is an excellent choice, or some Hunter group.

Comment: @Pryodante, does nWoD still have the New World Order convention of the technocracy? There you've got somewhat of a literal MIB :)

Comment: @BrianS Neither the NWO nor the Technocracy are in nWoD. However, Division Six from Witch Finders serves a similar role. :)

Answer (score 5):

**No.**

There isn't a specific book that covers how all the various supernatural things remain hidden from the mass of humanity.

As noted in the question each of the main lines explain how their given type remains hidden from mortals and these reasons vary.

The widely accepted (and possibly stated in the core rules?) explanation is that humanity remains ignorant via something like an universal subconscious effort to ignore the weirdness.  Werewolves, vampires, mages, etc don't fit into our mental understanding of the universe and it's just easy to dismiss them rather then explain them and realize just how truly scary the world is.

Comment: Agreed, it seems to be kept vague (what, vagueness? in WoD? never! :P) to emphasize that each ST's world is a little different. One ST may have mortals acknowledge magic/vampires/etc but actively ignore it, due to being so very rare... while another may have them completely unawares... and another may be all "True Blood" with it being out in the open and just part of everyday life.